# Cython crashes when initializing c++ object

Tags: c++, cython

This is my first time using Cython, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going wrong.

I have a C++ class that takes in some filenames as strings, reads a bunch of parameters out of the files, and performs some heavy calculations. I've tested it extensively in C++ but I want to use it in Python. I took an example from [here](http://www.scientificpython.net/uploads/1/1/5/9/11598566/linearinterp1d.pdf), edited it to fit my class, and came out with the following:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = linterp1d.cpp
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "<vector>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass vector[T]:
        cppclass iterator:
            T operator*()
            iterator operator++()
            bint operator==(iterator)
            bint operator!=(iterator)
        vector()
        void push_back(T&)
        T& operator[](int)
        T& at(int)
        iterator begin()
        iterator end()


cdef extern from "parameterizedeos.h":
    cdef cppclass parameterizedEOS:
        parameterizedEOS(vector[string],vector[double])
        double pressure(double, double)
        double Cv(double, double)
        double Cp(double, double)
        double entropy(double, double)
        double enthalpy(double, double)
        double getDensityFromPressure(double, double)

cdef class parameterized_EOS:
    cdef parameterizedEOS *thisptr
    # Automatically converts NumPy arrays to STL vectors
    def __init__(self,vector[string] filenames,vector[double] parameters):
        self.thisptr = new parameterizedEOS(filenames, parameters)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def pressure(self,double rho, double T):
        return self.thisptr.pressure(rho, T)

    def enthalpy(self,double p, double T):
        return self.thisptr.enthalpy(p, T)

    def entropy(self,double p, double T):
        return self.thisptr.entropy(p, T)

    def Cv(self,double p, double T):
        return self.thisptr.Cv(p, T)

    def Cp(self,double p, double T):
        return self.thisptr.Cp(p, T)

    def getDensityFromPressure(self,double p, double T):
        return self.thisptr.getDensityFromPressure(p, T)
```

(For anyone who's curious, the class is an implementation of [this equation](http://www.nist.gov/srd/upload/jpcrd516.pdf).)

Here's the code I'm using to test it:

```
import numpy as np
import cython
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.string cimport string
from parameterizedeos import parameterized_EOS


def __main__():
    cdef string str1 = "D:\\Loop Models\\Sodium\\co2_helmholtz_idealgas_coeffs.csv"
    cdef string str2 = "D:\\Loop Models\\Sodium\\co2_helmholtz_real_coeffs_1.csv"
    cdef string str3 = "D:\\Loop Models\\Sodium\\co2_helmholtz_real_coeffs_2.csv"
    cdef string str4 = "D:\\Loop Models\\Sodium\\co2_helmholtz_real_coeffs_3.csv"
    cdef string str5 = "D:\\Loop Models\\Sodium\\co2_helmholtz_real_coeffs_4.csv"

    co2_coeffs = np.array([str1, str2, str3, str4, str5])
    co2_params = np.array([304.128, 467.6, 0.1889241e3])
    co2_eos = parameterized_EOS(co2_coeffs, co2_params)
    print(co2_eos.enthalpy(3e6, 700))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    __main__()
```

The above will compile, but when I run it Python just crashes with no explanation as to why. I'm guessing that the numpy array is not translating correctly to `std::vector<std::string>`, which would indeed cause the constructor of the C++ class to throw errors. So I have two questions: How do I figure out if that's really the problem, and if it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you think it's the conversion from the numpy arrays to `std::vector` you should probably try creating a simpler example that just does this (and skips your C++ class). You could also use a list of strings rather than a numpy array, which is the more standard way of doing things.